# Why do some arrays seem to have key value pairs

Tags: node.js

I have been playign with the RegExp system and one thing I noticed that was weird is I console logged a result like this:

```
[
    "match",
    "another thing",
    input: "my reg exp"
]
```

but when I try to asign it to a variable, it doesn't work. I can even access that weird var like this:

```js
const weirdVar = func();

console.log(weirdVar[0]); // match
```

I tried creating it like this too:

```js
const vari = {
    "a",
    "b",
    input: "lol"
};
```

None seem to work. With this I also saw some functions returning this!

```
RowDataPacket { id: 'Hello space', message: 'uwu' }
```

It's and array too im guessing as I can get data with `[0]`

```
[
  RowDataPacket { id: 'Hello space', message: 'uwu' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 'test', message: 'ME' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 'test', message: 'ME' }
]
```

What is this weird data type?

Comment: `const a = ["a", "b"]; a["input"] = "lol"; console.log(a)`.

Comment: Ohh array abuse, What about the second object with RowDataPacket as a prefix, what is that

Comment: `class A { constructor(name) { this.name = name; } }; const a = new A('ME'); console.log(a);`

Comment: Wow thanks, dont you think you should post it as an answer so i can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variable is an array. An array also is an object, which means it has attribute keys and values. But, the attribute keys of a normal array are numbers (index), and you can add an additional key to an array as an object.

```
const arr = ['index 0 value'];
arr[1] = 'index 1 value'; // attribute key is `1`;
arr.input = 'input value';
arr['output'] = 'output value';

console.log(arr);
```

The second result, `RowDataPacket` is an es6 class type

```
class RowDataPacket {
  constructor(id, message) {
    this.id = id;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

const instance = new RowDataPacket("new id", "new message");

console.log(instance);
console.log([instance]);
```